# Can't find error in $\int{xe^{-(x-\theta)}}dx$

Tags: integration

I haven't done integrals in some time and I'm kinda rusty. This is a very easy one, but for some reason I keep getting a slightly different result than the correct one. There has to be a sign error somewhere which I really can't find.

$$\int{xe^{-(x-\theta)}}dx $$
Let $t = x-\theta$. Then the above is:
$$\int{(t+\theta)e^{-t}dt = \int{te^{-t}dt}+\theta\int{e^{-t}dt} =-e^{-t}(t+1) -\theta e^{-t} = -e^{-t}(t-\theta+1) + c = -e^{\theta-x}(x-2\theta+1) + c}$$

However the correct results is $-e^{\theta-x}(x+1) +c$. The two thetas should cancel out but they don't. Where's my mistake?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sign error, $-e^{-t}(t+1) - e^{-t}\theta = -e^{-t}(t + \theta + 1)$.

Comment: that was such a silly mistake! thank you

Comment: Suggestion: Just use $e^{-(x-\theta)} = e^\theta\cdot e^{-x}$, and pull the $e^{\theta}$ out of the integral to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake as at the end of your solution:
$-e^{-t}(t+1)-\theta e^{-t} = -e^{-t}(t + 1 + \theta)$, not $-e^{-t}(t + 1- \theta)$, as you write, so now $-e^{-t}((x-\theta)+1+\theta)=-e^{-t}(x+1)$.

Comment: Could you edit this so the text isn't in math environments?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I've edited your answer to improve the formatting and readability. You might want to check over it to make sure that I haven't made any errors in transcription or otherwise changed the meaning of what you intended to write (and maybe also get some formatting tips: the major change is putting words outside of the dollar signs, rather than trying to set the spacing manually).

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$\int e^{-t} dt=-e^{-t}+C$$

Comment: yes my bad, I corrected it. As you can see, the next step was using $-\theta$ so it was just a typo in the previous step, not the actual mistake